# Navigation toolbar extends vertically after returned from full screen video

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

The first screenshot is taken before playing video in full screen.

[image: before]

The second is taken after the video is opened in full screen and closed.

[image]

Any idea why navigation toolbar has extend?

Note: The hamburger button is not the part of the navigation item. It is faked in overlay in parent that holds its child controller inside standard container.

Nothing special inside the source:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    bbiListic = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(identifier: .IcoHeaderListic), style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.showListic))
    bbiFavorite = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(identifier: .IcoHeaderStarEmpty), style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(LiveDogadjajViewController.toggleFavorite(_:)))

    ... 
    let items = [bbiListic!,bbiFavorite!]

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items
}

func someRefresh() {
    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    items.append(bbiListic!)
    ...
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items
}
```

**Update:**

This appears to be a problem only on the latest version of **iOS, 9.3**

Comment: can you put the code that you are setting navigation bar custom or setting button. i think you make +20px add for show the statusbar forst so might be that code calls once your are close the video player screen

Comment: Can you try removing hamburger menu functionality and check if same issue occurs?

Comment: are you using autolayout for constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the Apple developer technical support about this issue.
They have determined it is probably a **bug** in iOS 9.3.

Bug id: 26439832, iOS SDK

This is easy workaround for view controller on stack:

```
// ... add this to init method
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didExitFullscreen(_:)), name: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification, object: nil)

func didExitFullscreen(notification: NSNotification)
{

     // hack, fix for 9.3. 
     if #available(iOS 9.3, *)
     {
         navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
         navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
     }
}
```

Comment: ohk. Bug in iOS9.3. Thanks for sharing useful information.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshots, it look like that height of status bar gets doubled. Try this:-

Before playing your video, hide the status bar

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
```

After ending the video, show the status bar

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .None)
```

Comment: I didn't get lucky with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-requisite:

a) Uncheck "extends edges" by selecting your *uiviewcontroller* from *main.storyboard*

b) no constraints exist between your video player and container controller

Solution:

Check if any of your buttons on the nav bar are bottom constrained. Either remove that constraint or apply a fixed height constraint to your custom nav bar view so that it stays the same height.